# No module when importing from another python file (Mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm trying to import a python file from a different directory. Here is the current layout:
[image]

And here is the start of my code for `extendednb.py` in `v3/`:

```
import os
import sys
import keyboard
from extensions.incognito import incog
from extensions.media import main as media_Main
from extensions.settings import main as setting_Main

from extensions.settings.main import *
from extensions.media.main import *
from extensions.incognito.incog import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
```

I am importing `v3/extensions/settings/main.py` in line 6 of this file.
From `v3/extensions/settings/main.py` I am importing `./theme/main.py` using:

```
import sys
import keyboard
from theme import main as theme_Main
import restart

from restart import restart_program
from theme.main import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
```

(imported in line 3)

When I run this file, everything works fine without errors, however when I try and run `v3/extendednb.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/_/Documents/Documents – _'s MacBook Air/Python/browser/version3/v3/extendednb.py", line 6, in <module>
    from extensions.settings import main as setting_Main
  File "/Users/_/Documents/Documents – _’s MacBook Air/Python/browser/version3/v3/extensions/settings/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from theme import main as theme_Main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'theme'
```

Please help because this is the first time I have encountered this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it, with `./settings/theme.py` I put in the relative directories to `extendednb.py` instead